# Firebase Database full JSON to List - Flutter

Tags: json, database, firebase, flutter, http

I'm loading a Json file from local disk, to a list named **mydata** in my flutter project:

```
    String jsonfile;    
    jsonfile = "assets/derechopenal.json"

    future: DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString(jsonfile, cache: false),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        List mydata = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());
    
     return testpage(mydata: mydata)
                                   }
```

How can I get this json file in the same way, if now its uploaded in a firebase database?

```
https://opositestgc.firebaseio.com/derechopenal
```

I have already added all needed dependecies and packages, [as seen here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup) and im stuck at the code request. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Realtime Database SDK for Flutter doesn't return raw JSON data, but instead returns an object model representing the underlying data. So if you use the SDK, you'll have to use that object model as shown in the [example for the library](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_database/example).

If you want to stick to using raw JSON, you can use the [REST API to access the Firebase Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start). This will return the raw JSON, that you can then continue to use as you've been using the JSON from the file.